# Skip one maven test does not work

Tags: java, maven

I try to skip one test with my maven command (doc: https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/10/run-one-or-exclude-one-test-with-maven/):

```
mvn -B clean install -T2C -pl sub-tests -Dtest=!com.xx.xx.test.xx.xx.canMakeCall*
```

But I get some error (it seems it tries to skip all tests? I don't know):

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ sub-tests ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project sub-tests: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you miss @Test annotations at your tests?

Comment: No there are @Test annotations above all the tests

Comment: It looks you don't execute an test at all with your command: ` No tests were executed!`.. I would just try to run via `mvn -B clean install` nothing else...furthermore `-T2C` on a single sub module does not make sense..

Comment: Is your surefire plugin correctly configured? (naming patterns e.g.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to **[Maven Surefire Plugin - Running a Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)** :

> Running a Set of Methods in a Single Test Class
>
> As of Surefire 2.7.3, you can also run only a subset of the tests in a
>   test class.
>
> **NOTE : This feature is supported only for Junit 4.x and TestNG. Use syntax e.g. "foo/MyTest.java", "**/MyTest.java", "MyTest" for "test"
>   parameter (see includes/excludes).**
>
> You should use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test
> ```

So I think your command should be:

```
mvn -B clean install -T2C -pl sub-tests -Dtest=!com.xx.xx.test.xx.xx#canMakeCall*
```

It will ignore all tests methods starting with `canMakeCall` of test `com.xx.xx.test.xx.xx`.